# Scala: how to pass HTML as JSON value?

Tags: html, json, scala, playframework

How to transfer HTML in JSON?
According to [JSON validation rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example) for `String`s we need to escape `"`:

> String: a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters. Strings are
>   delimited with double-quotation marks and support a backslash escaping
>   syntax.

So the question is how to process html string, in order to pass it to JSON and get a valid JSON doc in the end?

Let's consider this html:

```
<h1>Document</h1>
<p>Hello, welcome to wonderful web!</p>
<p>Start from visiting <a href="www.google.com">Google</a></p>
```

Applying `.replace("\"", "\\\"")` to a `String` with html content in Scala does not work.

I use [spray-json](https://github.com/spray/spray-json) `.parseJson` in order to validate the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import play.api.libs.json._

// basic types

```
val jsonString = Json.toJson("Fiver")
val jsonNumber = Json.toJson(4)
val jsonBoolean = Json.toJson(false)
```

// collections of basic types

```
val jsonArrayOfInts = Json.toJson(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4))
val jsonArrayOfStrings = Json.toJson(List("Fiver", "Bigwig"))
```

Comment: Good advice! But instead of play-json lib I applied `.toJson` from spray-json